# Why some operations do not apply to an element with two CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two input elements and a button as follows:

```
<input class="close-acc-usr opt-in" type="text" name="closeAccUsr" />
<input class="close-acc-pin opt-in" type="number" name="closeAccPin" />
<button class="opt-btn close-btn">→</button>
```

In js I want to by clicking on the button, both input element contents become clear, so I write this line of code in the button event handler function:

```
document.querySelector('.opt-in').value = '';
```

but it does not work!! in fact if I write above code for '.close-acc-pin' and '.close-acc-usr' class names instead of .opt-in it works! but why with '.opt-in' it does not work?

Comment: `querySelector` returns only the first element it finds. And if you use `querySelectorAll` instead, you can not set the value for the elements via that - you need to _loop over_ the elements this returns, and set the value for each one of them individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to select all inputs with `querySelectorAll` :

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.opt-btn')
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.opt-in');
  inputs.forEach(input => input.value = '')
})
```

```html
<input class="close-acc-usr opt-in" type="text" name="closeAccUsr" />
<input class="close-acc-pin opt-in" type="number" name="closeAccPin" />
<button class="opt-btn close-btn">→</button>
```

Comment: I guess, cycling through all document.getElementsByClassName('opt-in') while setting their value empty would do the same job...  Maybe the "real" question meant, was how to make it possible by one-line code, though?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two classes for that input why not change that `opt-in` class into an id like this:

```
<input id="opt-in" class="close-acc-usr" type="text" name="closeAccUsr" />
```

→

Then in your JS this:

```
document.querySelector('#opt-in').value = '';
```

or better still this

```
 document.getElementById('opt-in').value = '';
```